# Python mocking the right class/import

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to implement unittests for my python program. The problem is, that my program is using several imported classes, which I would like to replace by a mocked object/class to verify single functions/methods.

I do not get any errors with my mocked class. But it appears that the mock itself didn't replace the object I wanted to replace.

This is basically my structure:

First the class I want to mock. Might look like that:

```py
class ToMock():
    def getSomething(self):
        return "something"
```

The class I want to test looks like this:

```py
from x.y import ToMock

class ClassToTest():
    def __init__(self):
        self.obj = ToMock()

    def returnStuff():
        return self.obj.getSomething()
```

As you can imagine, I want to test the `returnStuff` method. Therfore I want to mock `.getSomething`, or better said the whole `ToMock` object.

The unittest should therefore test the `ClassToTest` with the mocked `ToMock` class. I tried several `mock.patch` variants, but I couldn't get it to run/test properly.

```py
import unittest
from unittest import mock

from a.b import ClassToTest

class TestObject(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        with mock.patch('x.y.ToMock') as mock_obj:
            mock_obj.return_value.getSomething().return_value="mocked return value"
            self.test_class = ClassToTest()
            result = self.test_class.returnStuff() # This should return now 'mocked return value', I guess?
            mock_obj.return_value.getSomething.assert_called_once_with("")
```

The problem I face is, that the `self.test_class.returnStuff()` is not "calling" the mocked object, but imports the real class etc. and therefore I am running into timeouts, or similar stuff.

I am sure, that I provide the wrong path for the object which should be mocked. Perhaps someone can hint me into the right direction.

Thanks
-GreNait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are not patching in the correct place. You are patching where the object is *defined* as opposed to where it is *looked up*.

```
a.py
    -> Defines ToMock

b.py
    -> from a import ToMock
    -> some_function/class instantiates ToMock
```

In your code shown you are patching `a.ToMock` however you should be patching `b.ToMock`. That is why it is not running your mock object when testing. You can read more about [where to patch here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch).

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I tried exactly that before, I did however use the wrong "absoluty" path, I would say. Instead of with `mock.patch('x.y.ToMock')` I used `with mock.patch('a.b.ToMock')` but `b` is not the Class but the python module name! Thanks again!